# Splitting a paragraph into sentences in Java

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I am working on a task where I need to split a paragraph into sentences. For example given a paragraph:

```
"This is a long string with some numbers 123.456,78 or 100.000 and e.g. some abbreviations in it, which shouldn't split the sentence. Sometimes there are problems, i.e. in this one. here and abbr at the end x.y.. cool."
```

**I need below 4 sentences:**

```
This is a long string with some numbers 123.456,78 or 100.000 and e.g. some abbreviations in it, which shouldn't split the sentence.

Sometimes there are problems, i.e. in this one.

here and abbr at the end x.y..

cool
```

Now it is very much similar to [this task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784676/split-string-into-sentences-ignoring-abbreviations-for-splitting) which is implemented in JavaScript.

```
var re = /\b(\w\.\w\.)|([.?!])\s+(?=[A-Za-z])/g; 
var str = 'This is a long string with some numbers 123.456,78 or 100.000 and e.g. some abbreviations in it, which shouldn\'t split the sentence. Sometimes there are problems, i.e. in this one. here and abbr at the end x.y.. cool.';
var result = str.replace(re, function(m, g1, g2){
  return g1 ? g1 : g2+"\r";
});
var arr = result.split("\r");
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

I am trying to implement this in Java with help of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582142/splitting-a-string-using-regex-in-java) but got stuck how to use the `replace` function from above snipper in my Java code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String content = "This is a long string with some numbers 123.456,78 or 100.000 and e.g. some abbreviations in it, which shouldn't split the sentence. Sometimes there are problems, i.e. in this one. here and abbr at the end x.y.. cool.";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/\\b(\\w\\.\\w\\.)|([.?!])\\s+(?=[A-Za-z])/g");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
    List<String> tokens = new LinkedList<String>();
    while (m.find()) {
        String token = m.group(1); // group 0 is always the entire match
        tokens.add(token);
    }

    System.out.println(tokens);
}
```

How to do the same in Java programming? Is there a better approach than this to split a paragraph to sentences in Java for this given sample text?

Comment: Sentence 3 would usually be thought improper English because we don't write two periods at the end of a sentence.

Comment: and it doesn't contain a verb. Neither does sentence 4.

Comment: @user207421, I am trying to convert the working Javascript code to Java but I am not able to understand how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String content = "This is a long string with some numbers 123.456,78 or 100.000 and e.g. some abbreviations in it, which shouldn't split the sentence. Sometimes there are problems, i.e. in this one. here and abbr at the end x.y.. cool.";
    BreakIterator bi = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance();
    bi.setText(content);
    int index = 0;
    while (bi.next() != BreakIterator.DONE) {
        String sentence = content.substring(index, bi.current());
        System.out.println(sentence);
        index = bi.current();
    }
}
```